# How to change color and shape in a plot

Tags: latex, tikz

I am using tikz to plot a graph using a construction like:

```latex
\draw plot [mark=ball] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) ...};
```

However I would like to be able to change the color and the shape of the ball - it appears as a blue circle. I did not find (or did not understand) how to do it. A simple example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{ball}{\shade[draw=none,ball color=green] (0,0) circle (\pgfplotmarksize);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot [mark=ball] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A bit late, unfortunately, but we did it!

No need to say the trick you needed is line 2 ([reference](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=24308), more recent than your post).

Comment: Your example uses standalone, xkeyval, ..., which are not present in may installation. I might go back to it if I need it again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tsf sorry I had missed this comment...anyway, for future readers, you can copy/paste everything but the documentclass line, being only careful to recall tikz package with command usepackage.

Comment: That's OK. I will have to go back to my old 2012 files  and remember what it as about! Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
\draw [color=green, mark=triangle] plot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) ...};
```

if i understood you right.

As color you can set i.e red,green, blue, black,... and as mark i.e circle, o,x, star ,....

Comment: No, it does not work.  Your suggestion makes the originally black curve become green and no mark appears!  I wanted the mark to be a ball of a different color.

-- tsf